# remove line breaks but not double line breaks- Python

Tags: python, regex

i have text that has excessive line breaks that i want to remove. the goal is to remove the single line breaks \n BUT leave the double line breaks \n\n (indicating new paragraph), this is ok.

i created this regex to isolate the single breaks and try to sub for a nothing, an empty space, even a backspace '\b' but nothing works. the goal is to NOT have the sentence break on the single \n and have the sentence naturally continue on screen or do a self word wrap but not forced to a new line for a single \n. The consecutive linebreaks \n\n (see the end of sentence) are ok.

i added the * * so you can see them easier. the regex is supposed to capture the single \n (\\n) only when it is in front of 2 consecutive letters (?<=[a-z][a-z])

```
text = "more  information*\n*on options  concepts  and  strategies.*\n* Also,*\n*  George  Fontanills  publishes*\n*several  options *\n*learning  tools  that  deal*\n*primarily with the Delta Neutral approach.*\n\n*Page 14 shows and example of the tools"

text1= re.sub( r"(?<=[a-z][a-z])(\\n)" , " ", text)
```

Comment: Why are you editing this question after you have accepted an answer, and it has been closed as a duplicate? Are you disagreeing with the reason for it being closed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import re

text = "more  information*\n*on options  concepts  and  strategies.  Also,  George  Fontanills  publishes*\n*several  options  learning  tools  that  deal*\n*primarily with the Delta Neutral approach.*\n\n*Page 14 shows and example of the tools a\n"

text = text.replace("*", "")
text1= re.sub(r'(?<=[a-z., ]{2})\n(?!\n)', '', text)

print(text1)
```

Explanation:

1. Match a single character present in the list below `[a-z]{2}`. `{2}` Quantifier — Matches exactly 2 times.
2. `\n` matches a line-feed (newline) character (ASCII 10)
3. Negative Lookahead `(?!\n)`. Assert that the Regex below does not match.

Comment: thanks, but this solution eats the last 2 letters it checks for. so in 1st example, "information\noptions"  becomes "informati options"... same for other examples

Comment: @jonrios Can you try with my edit now?

Comment: thanks I change it from ?= to ?<= and it works. i had another request since testing.  in case for future. how do i handle a period or comma or space instead of 2 straight characters. so any combination of ( ?<=(\w | \d | \.| \, | \s) {2} ) this fails. So it should say, any combination of any 2 consecutive items (letter, number, period, comma, space) followed by 1 \n. can you adjust?

Comment: @jonrios, check my edit. This allows characters a-z or a period or comma or space. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: works as expected.  thanks for the many comebacks

Comment: @jonrios good luck

Answer (score 0):

You could use *{amount}* to indicate amount **\n** do you want remove:

```
text = text.replace('*', '')
re.sub(r"(?<=\w{2})(\n{1})", " ", text)
```

Comment: This does not work. Please test your solution before posting.

Comment: This works to me, at least in the example. Could you explain your comment?

Comment: The OP has mentioned at least 2 characters in the front. Your code removes the `\n` from this `a\n` as well.

Comment: Okey! I fix that

Comment: That isn't true,  code doesn't remove the `\n` from this `a\n` now.
\w{2} means two characters in `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

Comment: Your fix works now. But the downvote isn't from me.

Comment: thanks this does work, but how do i handle a period or comma or space instead of 2 straight characters. so any combination of ( ?<=(\w | \d | \.| \, | \s) {2} )  this fails. So it should say, any combination of any 2 items (letter, number, period, comma, space) followed by 1 \n